# Where should my application/service store its configuration files in windows?

Tags: java, windows, configuration-files

In Linux, I'll usually put user configuration files in $HOME/.myapp and in Windows I'll use APPDATA. So far so good.

What about non-user specific configuration? In linux, I'd put it into `/etc`. Is there an equivalent in Windows? Please note I would like to have the service running *before* any user logs in. Also, in case it plays a role, I'm developing in Java.

Alternatively: I approaching this the wrong way?

Comment: What about making it configurable via a property specified when starting the JVM: `java -Dnon.user.configuration.dir=C:/myfolder ...` This leaves it up to the user of your software where it should reside.

Comment: The problem with windows is that it has an unstable history of where the user settings are placed. (winxp: documents and settings, win vista/7/8: users) I think the idea of a configurable setting like hmjd proposes may be the best option. Keep in mind that I'm not a windows developer, so there might be tricks I don't know.

Comment: @hmjd thanks for your proposal. I do support a configurable location, but I still need to set a default, so I was looking for the "common practice"

Comment: @KurtDuBois Developers should not be hard coding paths to user profile location, they should be using *Known Folders* (via API, environment variables etc). Any well written program would not be affected by the change in path from WinXP to Vista

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows most "program files" for an app go in C:\Program Files\MyApp. The environment variable would be %ProgramFiles%\MyApp.

Comment: Thanks! A question though: if a non administrator user runs MyApp, then MyApp won't be able to write into `C:\Program Files\MyApp` right? Of course this is not a problem for my original question, since the app would be started by SYSTEM. Just curious. thanks!

Comment: The app itself should have no problem writing info to it if its XP. If its win 7 the app may have to run as admin because in win 7 the "program files" folder is considered a secure folder. So if a user tries to save info there they will be asked for admin credentials, if an admin tries to save info there they will just be asked to allow it. I'm not sure how the app itself would act trying to save info there. You can turn this behavior off however.

Answer (score 2):

You could use ALLUSERPROFILES as a base directory. This environment variable resolves to the C:\PROGRAMDATA folder in Windows7. Of course you need to add a specific folder for your applications

Comment: Aha, so that's where AllUsers went. That sounds like a good idea as well, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**In summary, you should use the known folder: ProgramData**.

To avoid hard coding of paths (and hence why I'm not providing them here) you should always retrieve the value via one of the following methods:

- The `%PROGRAMDATA%` environment variable (you can also use `%ALLUSERSPROFILE%` but I consider `%PROGRAMDATA%` more meaningful)
- For unmanaged code use [`SHGetKnownFolderPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/bb762188(v=vs.85).aspx), passing the [`FOLDERID_ProgramData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/dd378457(v=vs.85).aspx#FOLDERID_ProgramData).
- For managed code use [`System.Environment.GetFolderPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getfolderpath(v=vs.110).aspx), passing [`CommonApplicationData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder(v=vs.110).aspx).

This folder is not writeable by non-admins, so depending on your requirements you'll want to create a directory for your program and set the ACLs you need at install time.

Some good information on this topic is provided in the blog post: "[Where Should I Write Program Data Instead of Program Files](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-blog-archive/where-should-i-write-program-data-instead-of-program-files/ba-p/228513)".

For those interested in using other *Known Folders*, MSDN provides [extensive documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/dd378457(v=vs.85).aspx).